# I have an If statement that is not working, yet is logically correct

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

```
if ("tester" == findrange[117])
{
  var indict = 34;
}
if (keeperval[39] == "tester")
{
  var indict2 = 45;
}
if (keeperval[39] == findrange[117])
{
  var indict3 = 56;
}
```

This code will return when debugging will return these values:

indict = 34

indict2 = 45

indict3 = undefined

Does this make any sense? I just can't wrap my head around why this possibly wouldn't work!

Comment: Are both `keeperval[39]` and `findrange[117]` objects, or simple strings?

Comment: try `if (keeperval[39] === findrange[117])`

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EjLsF/

Comment: Might be that `==` is doing type coercion and thus changing objects/arrays to strings and comparing.

Comment: I am getting 34, 45 and 56 in fiddle and code seems to be fine.

Comment: I changed all of the "==" to "===" and indict, indict2, and indict3 all came back as undefined. A little more information that might help is I am running this is Google Script, and pulling these arrays as columns of data in Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wrapped your strings in `findrange[117]`  and `keeperval[39]` in `String`, instead of simply using a literal.

Therefor, both aren't strings, but instead string *objects*. When you use them in a comparison with strings, it will use the object's `.toString()`, therefor `== "tester"` will work.

However, when both sides of an equality comparison are objects, the result will be true if and only if both objects are actually the same:

```
var s1 = new String("test");
var s2 = new String("test");
console.log(s1 == s2); // logs false
```

So instead of

```
findrange[117] = new String("tester");
keeperval[39] = new String("tester");
```

use

```
findrange[117] = "tester";
keeperval[39] = "tester";
```

Even better, exchange your equality tests with type-safe equality tests:

```
if ("tester" === findrange[117])
{
  var indict = 34;
}
if (keeperval[39] === "tester")
{
  var indict2 = 45;
}
if (keeperval[39] === findrange[117])
{
  var indict3 = 56;
}
```

Then you will see instantly that there's something off. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjLsF/1/))

For further reference, see MDN's [JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), especially [sameness in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Sameness).

**EDIT:** If you're not able to change the type of the values in your arrays, use the `.toString()` method before comparing:

```
if ("tester" === findrange[117].toString())
{
  var indict = 34;
}
if (keeperval[39].toString() === "tester")
{
  var indict2 = 45;
}
if (keeperval[39].toString() === findrange[117].toString())
{
  var indict3 = 56;
}
```

Comment: I am pulling the data form a Google Spreadsheet not actually defining the arrays, so I am not sure whether they are using a literal or not. I also changed all of the "==" to "===", and indict, indict2, and indict3 all came back as undefined.

Comment: @tokyo_tech: As it was expected, seriously, read that guide :D. However, I edited my answer. If you don't know whether it's a string, you simply use `.toString()`. It works on everything (except literals).

Comment: Sorry, this was my first question, I will do better next time! But thank you for you help, I got it working! If I had enough reputation to Vote up your answer I would.

Answer (score 0):

use

> keeperval[39] === findrange[117]

to understand if both of them are objects or strings.

Answer (score 0):

try groovy console :

```
def findrange = ["tester","nontester"]

def keeperval = ["tester"]

if ("tester" == findrange[0])
{
  def indict = 34;
println indict

}
if (keeperval[0] == "tester")
{
  def indict2 = 45;
println indict2
}
if (keeperval[0] == findrange[0])
{
  def indict3 = 56;

  println indict3

}
```

`output :`
34
45
56

Answer (score 0):

First check the type
console.log(typeof(findrange[117]));

In your case this should be an object

In JS,

compare obj to string; will compare obj.value to string value

compare obj to obj; will compare references to the object and not value

Comment: Ohhhh. I see, yeah, that's the problem, how can I compare the object value with the object value? I checked the type using typeof, and it is object.

Comment: Two distinct objects are never equal for either strictly or abstract comparisons.:) .. you could try..  if (keeperval[39] + ""  == findrange[117])

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I used the "" and it worked wonderfully!